# No provider for InjectionToken auth0.client In Auth0 Sdk Angular 16 standalone configuration Project

Tags: angular, auth0, angular16

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[LoginComponent])[AuthorizationService -> AuthorizationService -> AuthService -> InjectionToken auth0.client -> InjectionToken auth0.client]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken auth0.client!
I tried to give provider and other thing not working for me.

Comment: Any solution fro this problem?